# C hexadecimal convert to a char pointer

Tags: c, networking, casting, ip, hex

So I have a piece of code which basically should convert first byte of IP address given in u_int32 (or hex) to a char*. For example, given a **192.168.10.49** (**0x31 0x0a 0xa8 0xc0**), should return **192** (**0xc0**). The IP address is given in network byte order. I have written a piece of code which works, however, I do not understand how and why it works as it is.

```
struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *) malloc(sizeof(addr));
unsigned char *ip_str;
int i = 0;

/* cast sockaddr to sockaddr_in. ip is given as an argument of sockaddr */
addr = (struct sockaddr_in*) ip;

/* cast address */
ip_str = (char *) &(addr->sin_addr.s_addr);

printf("addr: %02x\n", addr->sin_addr.s_addr);
printf("ip_str: %02x\n", (int) (*ip_str));
```

In this piece of code, I give a sockaddr struct which contains IP address in network byte order, and then I cast it to sockaddr_in struct. And finally, I cast my IP address, which is in u_int32 format, to a char pointer and get the result of **192** (given the ip is **192.168.10.49**). First printf functions prints the IP in hex, and its output is:

> 310aa8c0

The second one, the result, is printed as:

> c0

However, if I convert from network byte order to host byte order (using **ntohl()**), I get the result of:

> c0a80a31

And the second one prints:

> 31

And my question is, how does this cast works? Why does it cast to the last byte of IP address? Any links to some kind of tutorials about this or book references are welcome.

Comment: `ip` is not defined in the code

Comment: There is no need to allocate memory for `addr` dynamically. Especially since you then reassign `addr` leading to a memory leak, and possible undefined behavior when you later try to pass that pointer to `free`.

Comment: As for your question, it simply seems to me that you need to learn how integer numbers works or are stored in computers, and about [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Take a course about basic computer architecture, or at least find a tutorial or text book about it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, a tip about memory leak noted, didn't knew about that. I will look into endianness

Comment: @KamiKaze `ip` is a sockaddr struct I give through arguments, it is a code snippet taken from a function

Comment: @aretas_pau I understand what mean but generally it is appreciated when you post a [mcve]

Comment: @KamiKaze I will keep that in mind next time I post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network byte order is big-endian and apparently your host byte order is little-endian. Therefore, the byte string is reversed using `ntohl`.

Note that in

```
printf("ip_str: %02x\n", (int) (*ip_str));
```

`ip_str` is a pointer to `unsigned char`. Dereferencing it returns the first byte in `ip_str`.

Now, you wonder why the first, not the last byte is output. That's precisely because of endianness. In memory, your four-byte `ip_str` is in little-endian format, i.e., the *least significant byte is stored as the first one*. So if you access that four-byte string not in its entirety but by accessing just the first byte, you access the last byte, in fact.

Comment: So, as I understood, it all comes down to how computer stores its bytes in memory?

Comment: @aretas_pau Precisely. What you are doing is implementation-defined because different computers have different endianness settings.

Comment: As for portability, such implementation is bad, I suppose?

Comment: @aretas_pau It's like your taking the words out of my mouth. Not well-defined, not portable, correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you for explanation. I will try to make it more portable and well-defined. It seems there is lots of interesting stuff to learn about